# How to create a Telegram channel, where users can't reply on announcements?

Tags: telegram, channel

I've been following a telegram channel of a festival, where i've been receiving messages with updated but has no reply option. Now i need to create one for my own festival, but can't find this option in setting. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create [Public Channel](https://telegram.org/tour/channels) not [Group Chat](https://telegram.org/tour/groups) for that.  Also when Channel is created you can specify group for discussions.
[image: create Channel button]